# Is there a way to change permissions for all the tables in SQL-server database at once?

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions

I want to change the permissions for all the tables in a SQL-Server database at once. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the results of this script (change to suit your requirements):

```
SELECT
    'GRANT SELECT ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) + ' TO myRole'
FROM
    sys.objects o
WHERE
    OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'IsMSSHipped') = 0
    AND
    OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'IsTable') = 1
ORDER BY
    OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided all of your tables belong to the same schema, you could modify permissions at the Schema level.

See [Grant Schema Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

Comment: ah, I always forget this option

Comment: Also many GRANTs have an ALL/ANY option, there are database level permissions that imply permissions on every object in the database, and there are fixed roles like db_datareader/db_datawriter. In other words, there are many many ways to skin this one.

Comment: I guess what Remus is alluding to is that it's really about identifying what works best for your environment in terms of manageability.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that retrieves the set of tables and then grants/denies permissions through dynamic SQL.

However, I think a better approach would be to create a role, grant rights to that role, and then add/remove individuals from that role as needed.